# R remove two sides of border from strip.background function

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

**Dataframe**

```
df <- data.frame(
structure(list(biological_group = structure(1:15, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
"O"), class = "factor"), norm_expression = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
1L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L), SE = c(0.171499719, 
0.089692493, 0.153777208, 0.188012958, 0.153776128, 0.192917199, 
0.224766056, 0.231338325, 0.121716906, 0.094763028, 0.09635363, 
0.069986333, 0.113681329, 0.094614957, 0.391182473), Group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"Plant Products", "Sugars"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), .Names = c("biological_group", "norm_expression", "SE", 
"Group")))
```

**Sample code**

```
library(ggplot2)

DFplot <-  ggplot(df, aes(biological_group,norm_expression)) + 
  ylab("Relative Normalized\nExpression (∆∆Cq)") + 
  geom_bar(fill="black",stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())

DFplot2 <- DFplot+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=norm_expression-SE,ymax=norm_expression+SE),width=0.5) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(~Group, scales = "free_x", switch = "x", space = "free_x") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1)) + 
  theme_classic()
```

That gives me this graph:
[image]

I'd like to remove the vertical lines from the strip text labels (specified by strip.background), like this:
[image]

I realize I could just use photoshop or something, but I have several graphs to make so it would be easier if I could just specify it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471816/remove-three-sides-of-border-around-ggplot-facet-strip-label) was helpful.

In your case, you want to find the `strip-b` for your bottom strips to substitute.

**Edit**: Replaced top bar of bottom strip that was removed accidentally.

```
library(grid)

q <- ggplotGrob(DFplot2)

lg <- linesGrob(x=unit(c(1,0),"npc"), y=unit(c(1,1),"npc"), gp=gpar(col="black", lwd=2))

for (k in grep("strip-b",q$layout$name)) {
  q$grobs[[k]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[1]] <- lg
}

grid.draw(q)
```

[image: fixed bottom strip rect with top/bottom removed]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is it possible to also add in the top line?