# How to change color of certain border of strip area of ggplot object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

code of plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), disp)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(. ~ gear, switch = "x") +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "red")
  )
```

[image]

I'm trying to modify the color of certain borders:
Expected output:

[image]

I tried to change it using grobs but it seems that specific borders cannot be changed.

```
p <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), disp)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(. ~ gear, switch = "x") +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "red")
  )

g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g$grobs[[13]]$grobs[[1]]$children$strip.background.x..rect.33641$gp$col
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471816/remove-three-sides-of-border-around-ggplot-facet-strip-label) answer, you can change the border with `linesGrob`. In your case you will need `polylineGrob` because you need two unconnected lines (one on each side of the grids).

**Code**

```
p <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), disp)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(. ~ gear, switch = "x") +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_rect(color = NA)
  )

library(grid)
q <- ggplotGrob(p)

lr2 <-  polylineGrob(x=c(0,0,1,1),
                      y=c(0,1,0,1),
                      id=c(1,1,2,2),
                      gp=gpar(col="blue", lwd=3))

for (k in grep("strip-b",q$layout$name)) {
  q$grobs[[k]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[1]] <- lr2
}

grid.draw(q)
```

**Plot**

[image]